# Can't find ruby or gem commands after doing ruby-install in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apt-get, ruby-install

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine following the instructions in https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install and executing the following command:

```
sudo ruby-install ruby 1.9.3
```

I was assuming this would link from my /usr/bin or somewhere else visible from my path ruby or gem, but it doesn't. When I try for example: `gem install bundler`, I get:

```
sudo: gem: command not found
```

It also can't find ruby when I try `ruby -v`.

If I install with `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3`, I'm able to execute both ruby and gem:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
1.8.11
```

I was expecting from ruby-install the same output I got from apt-get. Am I looking in the wrong place? How do I run ruby and gem after installing with ruby-install?

I know there are other installers for ruby like rvm and rbenv, but I'm following some installations instructions and they clearly instruct to use ruby-install.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read this ... There are two ways for installing ruby .1) using rbenv 2) using rvm ,.... read here . https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04#ruby

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @NullSoulException. I've updated my questions, since although there are other ruby installers, I'm following some instruction manual for an application and it clearly instructs to use ruby-install.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the answer.

After running

```
sudo ruby-install ruby 1.9.3
```

the last line from the log is:

```
>>> Successfully installed ruby 1.9.3-p547 into /opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547
```

Which I have no excuse for not paying attention to since it's in bold colourfull letters.

Erm, anyway, adding `/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547` to the PATH makes `ruby` and `gem` work.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin
```